# can't ssh to ec2 instance connection refused?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, connection, ubuntu-12.04

I was working on an ec2 instance, running some simulations on it.I was able to ssh to the instance
in the office but when I came back to hostel(using ethernet in college) I was unable to ssh
I got the error:
`ssh: connect to host <IP of instance> port 22: Connection refused`.So what is the problem??
My ssh is running , of course openssh is installed and in college I am able to ssh to localhost.So is this a problem with proxy/network settings??

Comment: You could try using -v to see where its failing. Multiple -v statements increases the verbosity.

Comment: most likely: your hostel blocks port 22 or you need to login on some site with a browser before getting "real" internet. does surfing the web work? can you connect to the ip via telnet port 22? port 80 (if there is a webserver running)?

Comment: @mnagel yes I can surf the web, can't connect via telnet

Comment: @sasha can you connect to *any* host via ssh? can you (still) connect to your ec2 from somewhere else? i strongly suspect port 22 is blocked in your hostel. maybe it is enough to make your sshd listen on another port, 80 or 443 being good guesses.

Comment: @mnagel I can connect to the instance from my office using internet connection there on the same laptop

Comment: @mnagel how to make sshd listen to a different port ??

Comment: http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2006/10/11/running-an-ssh-server-on-multiple-ports

Comment: @mnagel Does not work now gives the same error for port 80 and 32022!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem I had to get pass through the proxy of my college
for that I added this to my /etc/ssh/ssh_config file `Host *
ProxyCommand corkscrew <put you proxy here> <port> %h %p`